# Vertical alignment with multirow in tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx, multirow

I have looked around for a solution that allows me to vertically centrally align a `multirow` row that spans two intermediate rows, which potentially span multiple lines since the tabular environment is `tabularx`.

Some other questions that don't quite get to the solution are [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43816/8863), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66596/8863), and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73160/8863). These solutions use the `fixup` parameter to `multirow` that I really would not like to use, or they are not quite applicable to my case.

So, to give an example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx, multirow, booktabs, lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXX}
\toprule
a & the first very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very long line. & a \\
\multirow{2}{*}{b} & a very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very long line. & \multirow{2}{*}{b} \\
                   & another very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very long line. &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

I would like the "b"s to be vertically centrally aligned. I am not tied in any way to `multirow`, but I am to `tabularx` and would very much prefer an automatic solution.

Comment: What do you mean that you are not `"tied in any way to multirow"`? If you are just after centering the text vertically as well as horizontally in each cell (not in multirow cells), then `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}` will work. Then you can also define a new column type for horizontal centering.

Comment: Well, not tied in any way to multirow means that if some other package can be used (as I got the impression from the other solutions) to achieve the outcome, then that is fine.
Your solution would _not_ center it to both the cells, right?

Comment: I'm sorry. I am lost. I don't know of a package that does what the `multirow` package does. But I might be mistaken.

Comment: `multirow` enables one to write text that spans several rows. As explained by @Philipp in his answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66596/vertical-alignment-in-multirow-using-cells-with-1-lines), *"multirow is not capable of a correct vertical alignment, if it spans multi-line cells"*

Comment: I am not claiming that such a package exists. I am saying that if it did, I would abandon `multirow` in its favor. A number of the other solutions linked in the main question do just that, build solutions  which do not require the use of the `multirow` package.

Comment: "multirow is not capable of a correct vertical alignment, if it spans multi-line cells" hpesoj626, quite so. I am simply saying that `multirow` does part of what I want. With or without `multirow` I'd like a solution to my entire requirement. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

This is using a pdftex primitive but it or similar are available in other engines. It takes a couple of runs to settle down and assumes that the spanning rows are bigger than the entry being placed in the span (if the text in `\centerbetween` is to big it will overprint surrounding text with no warning). The `\advance\dimen@\ht\strutbox` factor in the code may need adjusting for your visual vertical centering. Without it it centers the middle of the text box between the top and bottom _baseline_s of the spanning rows which isn't usually quite what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx, multirow, booktabs, lipsum}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\savepos#1{\pdfsavepos\write\@auxout{%
\gdef\expandafter\string\csname savepos@#1@x\endcsname{\the\pdflastxpos}^^J%
\gdef\expandafter\string\csname savepos@#1@y\endcsname{\the\pdflastypos}}}

\def\centerbetween#1#2#3{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname savepos@#1@x\endcsname\relax
  \dimen@\z@
  \else
  \dimen@\csname savepos@#2@y\endcsname sp %
  \advance\dimen@-\csname savepos@#1@y\endcsname sp %
  \advance\dimen@\ht\strutbox
  \fi
  \smash{\raisebox{\dimen@}{\parbox[c]{\hsize}{#3}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXX}
\toprule
a & the first very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very long line. & a \\
\strut\savepos{a}%
\centerbetween{a}{b}{bbb}
& a very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very long line. &
\centerbetween{a}{b}{ccc} \\
\vfill\strut\savepos{b} 
                  & another very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very long line. &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's about three years ago, but for now I don't see any better solutions about this issue, many posts still suggest manually adjust the `fixup` parameter of the `multirow` package. So Is it possible to add this feature(save the top and bottom position of the merge cell and reuse it later) to the `multirow` package. I see many question about this issue, also I also have the need to vertical align texts in a merged cell. Thanks.

Comment: @ollydbg23 you'd have to ask the maintainer of that package, any of the code I post here can be used by anyone, or perhaps someone else would like to make a small package that just does this or....

Comment: I send an email to the author of `multirow` package, let's see their response. Thanks.